# Find a context-free grammar for $L = \{a^lb^n c^m |l, n, m ∈ \mathcal{N} + ∧ ((l ≥ n) ∨ (l ≥ m))\}$

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have to find a constext-free grammar for the language $L = \{a^lb^n c^m |l, n, m ∈ \mathcal{N} + ∧ ((l ≥ n) ∨ (l ≥ m))\}$. However, it seems hard to see where to start with the condition $((l ≥ n) ∨ (l ≥ m))$. All I know is we can't have strictly less number of a's than the number of b's or c's. I thought starting with $S \rightarrow XYZ$, but the rest is not that clear. Can you give a hint where to start?

**EDIT**

Can you tell if $S \rightarrow aAbc, S \rightarrow aBc$ with $A \rightarrow aAb, A \rightarrow a$ and $B \rightarrow aBc, B \rightarrow b$ is fine?

Answer (score 1):

I think this works:
$$ S\to aAbc^+\mid a^+Bc$$
$$ A\to aAb\mid a^+$$
$$ B\to aBc\mid b^+$$

(where $x^+$ is short for $x^+\to xx^+\mid x$)

Comment: @Robert I explained $+$, and $X\to Y\mid Z$ is short for $X\to Y$ and $X\to Z$.

Comment: This doesn't work. You can derive aabccccccccccccccccccccccc using this.

Comment: @Kaind which has $l=2, n=1, m\gg1$, so certainly $l\ge n$

Comment: Oh it's an 'or'. (I read it as an 'and'). My bad.